# Ambiente de manutenção para ecomerce - PrestaShop

Tags: php, git, deploy, e-commerce

Peguei um serviço para dar suporte a um e-commerce na plataforma PrestaShop.

Encontrei o ambiente configurado desta forma:

Os arquivos principais da aplicação estão no bitbucket. Para fazer a manutenção, eu altero os arquivos via `git` e faço o *deploy* do 
BitBucket para o servidor onde está a aplicação.

O problema é que, na área administrativa do site, quando se instala um plugin ou módulo, altera-se tanto arquivos de código fonte quanto o banco de dados, mas os arquivos são alterados no servidor e não no bitbucket e, além disso, o `git` não gerencia o banco de dados.

Gostaria de saber se existe um modelo de ambiente ou alguma solução para este problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é uma questão antiga que nem mesmo no forum oficial do PrestaShop obtém-se resposta.

Para aplicar os commits nos módulos terá que criar políticas de uso administrativo onde diversas funções úteis seriam bloqueadas, dentre elas, modificações nos themes, módulos, overrides dentre outros.

Sempre que precisar adicionar algum módulo, theme ou outra função dentro da situação que descreveu na pergunta, terá que fazê-lo primeiramente no ambiente de produção. Ou seja, não seria mais permitido controlar isso pelo BackOffice do PrestaShop, caso queira todo o controle pelo GIT.

Esse assunto vale também para outras plataformas modulares.

Você terá a vantagem de poder controlar pelo git, mas a plataforma perde parte importante dos recursos. Pois o atrativo desse tipo de plataforma é para que leigos em programação possam instalar recursos sem precisar saber nada de programação.

Mas a realidade é que nem sempre um módulo funciona bem quando atualizado. Por vezes provocam falhas onde necessita de um programador profissional e experiente para resolver. No final das contas, o recurso que permite um leigo instalar coisas sem saber o que está fazendo, torna-se uma faca de dois gunes.

**Sobre o banco de dados**, como controlar o versionamento da estrutura (schemas) é uma questão de opinião, mas normalmente faz-se um dump do schema e salva num arquivo texto comum. Assim poderá adicionar a estrutura ao controle do git. 
Há quem prefere também adicionar os dados (junto ou separado do schema). Depende muito da situação. Particularmente salvo partes essenciais de configurações. Os dados em si, os que consomem mais espaço como tabelas de pedidos, clientes, logs, produtos, etc, prefiro não manter junto nem mesmo no git. Salvo separadamente. Isso porque se salvar sempre todos os dados a cada commit, em pouco tempo o espaço nas mídias de armazenamento atingem a quota limite e é muto fácil disso acontecer pois uma loja simples, pequena, costuma ter pouco acima de 1GB de dados. Se você fizer 5 commits num dia, significa + 5GB somente de dados do banco e na maioria das vezes nem precisa ter toda essa informação "duplicada".

**Dica,** como você já pegou o projeto com essa estrutura e por estar fazendo esse tipo de pergunta, presumo que o responsável anterior não te forneceu instruções. Baseado nisso, aconselho a fazer um minucioso checkup entre o versionamento e os dados que estão em produção. Muito provavelmente deve ter modificações no ambiente de produção incompatíveis com o que está no git.

Portanto apenas tome cuidados com isso. Sugiro puxar tudo da produção via FTP, ou qualquer outro meio viável, e gerar um novo commit de tudo com a sua nova política administrativa e de gerenciamento, caso queira continuar controlando pelo git. Documente bem isso e forneça a documentação ao proprietário da loja para que o dia que você deixar de prestar o suporte, o próximo programador possa saber como dar continuidade.

Claro, antes de qualquer coisa, faça uma reunião com o proprietário para explicar a situação. A partir daí, formalize em contratos e prossiga com o serviço conforme o que for concordado porque tudo isso é serviço, é muito mais trabalhoso e deve ser onerado. Se o seu contrato de suporte não inclui esse nível minucioso de trabalho, você pode sair no prejuízo, trabalhando muito além do orçamento. Com o tempo isso vai acumulando e pesando para o seu lado.

Comment: Ajudou muito, vou decidir junto com o dono a melhor opção.